# How to auto indent <head> and <body> in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I notice that the auto formatting shortcut "shift+option+f" in vscode doesn't auto indent <*head*> and <*body*> sections.

Is there any way that I can indent them automatically?

Comment: i think there isnt any quick tool that auto indents them... The only quick thing you can do is: Mark the whole <head> and <body> sections and press tab

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P to open Command Palette. Type in settings and select Open User Settings.
2. In Search settings box, input indent to search for settings related to indentation. Select full in Editor: Auto Indent section.
3. Automatic indentation is now enabled. Changes are saved automatically and applies to all opened files as well.

Answer (score 0):

dentify the  and  areas
Identify block and span type elements
Add 2 more pages to the project and link them, “mycity.html”, “myhobbies.html”
Add different types of content (ie: photos, YouTube videos, etc...)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting that controls the indentation of `head` and `body` elements in html with vscode.  So enable this setting:

```
HTML > Format: Indent Inner HTML
// Indent <head> and <body> sections
```